# POSIX message queue security

Tags: c, posix

I'm developing some programs in C that intercommunicate through message queue.

So for example in the two programs there is a line like this:

`msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);`

They share the same key and the same message structure.

However was wondering: What about the security?

If another program write messages on the same queue of the two above could be a problem for me.
Do you have any kind of suggestion for dealing with security in the meaning of authentication and authorization?

Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `0666` permissions any process can access the message queue. You can make it more secure by using more restrictive permissions like `0600` so only the current user can access it.

Comment: Ok so if someone can run a program with the user privilege can send messages to my program? Is there any way for doing authentication?

Comment: You could of course put something password-like in your messages and discard messages not having it.